# Uncaught Error: Can’t resolve all parameters for PushObject: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

This error happened when I run on android.

I am using @ionic-native/push to receive push noti from my nodejs server.
This is my config:
Component.ts:

```
initPushNotification() {
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {},
      ios: {
          alert: 'true',
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {},
      browser: {
          pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
      }
   };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.subscribe('topic').then(() => {
      console.log('subscribe success to topic')
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('device token -> ' + data.registrationId);
      //TODO - send device token to server
    });

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
      console.log('Received a notification', notification)
    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin' + error));
  }
```

my app.modules.ts:

```
import { Push, PushObject } from '@ionic-native/push';

providers: [
...
    Push, PushObject,
...]
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't include the `PushObject` in the providers array, only the `Push` class (since that's the provider):

```
import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push';

providers: [
...
    Push,
...]
```